# Limpar campos de form ao desmarcar check

Tags: jquery

Tenho um `form` com um `check` que ao marcado mostra uma `div` com um input com o nome de `BancoFinanc`, o usuário pode preencher esse input normalmente, mas gostaria de ao desmarcar o check o input, se preenchido pelo usuário, fosse limpo.

O que tenho e o que tentei fazer foi isso, mas sem sucesso:

```
$(function () {
    $("#chkFinanciamento").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#dvFinanciamento").show();
        } else {
            $("#dvFinanciamento").hide();
            // LIMPA VARIÁVEL
            $("#dvFinanciamento > :BancoFinanc").val();         
        }
    });
});
```

E também essa:

```
$(function () {
    $("#chkFinanciamento").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#dvFinanciamento").show();
        } else {
            $("#dvFinanciamento").hide();
            // LIMPA VARIÁVEL
            $("#BancoFinanc").attr("value","");     
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para limpar o `input`, basta substituir:

```
$("#BancoFinanc").attr("value","");
```

por:

```
$("#BancoFinanc").val("");
```

Comment: Obrigado @Allan Andrade, resolveu o meu problema.